# Alternative library functions (including C++ code) assigned during .onLoad in R package

Tags: r, installation, rcpp, devtools, r-package

I am building an R package using `devtools` which uses a single function (say `f()`) from another package (say pkg_X). But pkg_X is pretty heavyweight, and depends on all sorts of graphical libraries which aren't needed for the function I want. However, it's distributed under MIT, so I can pull out the functions needed and stick them into my package.

My reasoning is, however, that this isn't needed if the user has already installed pkg_X for some other reason. So what I want to do is to check for `require("pkg_X")` during the `.onLoad()` function of my package, and if it fails, define my own version of `f()`.

An additional problem is that `f()` also depends on some C++ code which can be accessed using `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`. So at the moment in the `.onLoad` function I'm doing something like this (copied from https://community.rstudio.com/t/build-package-namespace-dynamically-during-onload/4101 )

```
## for NAMESPACE exporting
f <- NULL
cpp_func <- NULL

.onLoad <- function(lib, pkg, ...) {
  if (!suppressWarnings(require("pkg_X", character.only = TRUE))) {
    require(Rcpp)
    sourceCpp("alt_dir/mycppfile.cpp") #defines cpp_func()
    cpp_func <<- cpp_func #make globally accessible
    source("alt_dir/my_r_code.R") #defines f()
    f <<- f #make globally accessible
  }
}
```

Where `mycppfile.cpp` and `my_r_code.R` are present in an `alt_dir` directory in my package space.

I'm sure this is wrong - for example, when I do `devtools::install("my_package")` on my mac, it works for the time being, but doesn't install the `mycppfile.cpp` and `my_r_code.R` files into the right place, so that `library(my_package)` fails.

What is the right way to do this? I've not done any package development in R before, so I suspect I'm doing something silly.

Comment: tl;dr but you are not making sense: _either_ you write a package _or_ you argue about `sourceCpp()` but never at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand here. I'm writing a package that might sometimes use cpp code, or (if another package, pkg_X, exists in the R installation), does not need it. I'm using `sourceCpp()` to conditionally compile that code if needed. But that's probably wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest adding both `my_r_code.R` and `mycppfile.cpp` to your R package. Let them define functions `my_f` and `my_cpp_func` that are not exported.

Next I would add two wrapper functions `wrap_f` and `wrap_cpp_func` to the package that just do something like this:

```
wrap_f <- function(...) {
  if (require("pkg_X", quiet = TRUE)) {
    pkg_X::f(...)
  else {
    my_f(...)
  }
}
```

I find that easier to understand.

Comment: Ah, that's an option. But if I don't export them, do I have to use a triple colon instead?

Comment: @user2667066 No. Any function defined in your package is available within the package. You don't have to use double- or tripple-colon syntax.

Comment: Oh, I seem - you mean the wrapper functions are also defined in the package, and are exported from it. The slightly inconvenient thing about this is that it requires me to edit the original source files (here labelled my_r_code.R and mycppfile.cpp) from pkg_X and change the named of the functions, whereas with my previous setup, I could just copy the files without alteration.

Comment: I ended up doing this, but (so that I could keep the original `my_r_code.R` code files etc from pkg_X, which had `#' export` directives in), I edited the NAMESPACE file created by `document()` to remove some of the exports, and removed some autogenerated man pages from `my_r_code.R` too. I guess there's no way to tell `document()` to skip parsing some of the files - e.g. by putting them in a different dir, or by passing parameters to the function?

Comment: @user2667066 The files won't be part of the package if you put them into a different directory.

Comment: Thanks. I actually want the code in the files to be accessible (and compiled) during package installation - I just don't want `document()` to parse the `export` and documentation directives out of them. Is that possible?

Comment: @user2667066 I do not know a way to do that and I would be surprised if such a special need would be catered for by a general purpose tool.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case. I'm content to edit the NAMESPACE file by hand (even though the comment at the top says not to do this!)

Comment: I've found that packages change functions all the time (either renaming, or changing the output, etc.). So your package could easily break due to changes in the function,  unless you are sure the function will not change (e.g., in a well established package like dplyr). I would personally,  copy the function code and add them as a contributor/copyright holder in the DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: Also if you edit NAMESPACE by hand take out the roxygen comment at the top.